# Animation Preset in After Effects

Tags: animation, adobe, after-effects, preset

I want to create a scale-up and scale-down animation the first and last 7 frames of my layer. Is there a way to create an animation preset for this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
startScale = [0,0];
endScale = [100,100];
nombre_capa = "layer_name";

if(time < (thisComp.layer(nombre_capa).inPoint+thisComp.layer(nombre_capa).outPoint)/2) 
        ease(time,thisComp.layer(nombre_capa).inPoint,thisComp.layer(nombre_capa).inPoint+0.2,startScale,endScale) 
else 
ease(time,thisComp.layer(nombre_capa).outPoint-0.2,thisComp.layer(nombre_capa).outPoint,endScale,startScale);
```